# Compiling IE styles in a seperate stylesheet

Tags: css, internet-explorer, sass, stylesheet, conditional-comments

I'm looking at ways to compile all of my IE styles into a separate stylesheet to cut down on the file size of my main stylesheet. I would then pull in those IE styles using conditional comments.

I currently use Paul Irish's idea of targeting IE by adding classes to `<html>` http://www.paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/ see below:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="ie-8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html>         <!--<![endif]-->
```

So I can use the following:

```
.ie-test {
    background: green;

    .ie-8 & {
        background: red;
    }

}
```

This technique works fine but all styles are in included in the same stylesheet. I'd like to pull out the IE only stylesheets and compile those to a dedicated stylesheet. There are techniques around such as Jake Archibald's technique: http://jakearchibald.github.io/sass-ie/ that work with media queries but ideally I'd like to do something such as the following.

Assuming this is a partial with a file name of `_test.scss`:

```
.ie-test {
    @if $ie-only == true {
        background: red;
    }

    @else {
        background: green;
    }
}
```

I would then have two .scss files that pull in the relevant styles, one for IE:

```
$ie-only == true;

@import "test";
```

One for everything else:

```
@import "test";
```

My test's are very hit and miss so I was looking for some advice on the best way forward.

What I'm aiming for may not be possible, but it would be good to hear some thoughts.

Comment: Would using ie conditions to pull the specific stylesheet not work for you? Rather than using them to display a tag?

Comment: @Aaron I'm wanting to use conditional stylesheets, but I want that specific IE stylesheet to only include the IE styles I set in the .scss files. At the moment all of my styles for all browsers go into the same stylesheet, with specific IE classes added where needed. This means my main stylesheet can get quite heavy.

Comment: That “heaviness” of your stylesheet shouldn’t actually matter that much, after GZip compression …

Comment: SO is not a forum, this is not a place to "ask for advice".  If your implementation works as expected/desired, then I don't understand what the problem is.